# MSCOMCTLocx registering but still showing as 'Missing'

Tags: vba, windows-10

I am using VBA hosted in a drafting program called MicroStation. I have been using MSCOMCTL for the last few years to use controls such as Tab Views and ListViews. I have come back from a work trip and found my home PC to have a Windows Updated and im assuming that its broken it as i have found many articles relating to similar problems. 
MSCOMCTL will register and says it has succeed, but still shows as missing in the VBA IDE. Usually i can just use the regsvr32 command and it will work no problems.
I have researched alot and have found a heap of solutions, but none work for me. The main one seems to be to run.

```
regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\regtlib.ocx
```

But i cant find regtlib.ocx on my Windows 10 - 64 Bit PC.

With this VBA Program, the company where it is deployed is very restricted on what the users can do so im hoping to find an alternative to MSCOMCTL but still within VBA that i can somehow package / compile within my VBA file and doesnt need to be installed onto the PC. Either that or a solution to get the file working. I have been reading article after article and trying a heap of things over the past few days but nothing has worked. It seems at the moment that my best option is to redesign the forms without the Tab Control and List Views. But i find this crazy as they are microsoft files.
Thanks in advance!

So far i have tried the below (plus a couple more escape me at this time)

```
*Replacing MSCOMCTL.ocx with a downloaded version (backed up the original just in case)
*Replacing MSCOMCTL.ocx with a version installed with Office 2013, located under the program files x86/office/root etc.
*Registering MSCOMCTL in safemode to ensure it wasn't in use.
*Searching the C drive for regtlib.ocx as that has been known to fix it.
*I did find an alternative, but requires various files to be installed onto the PC which wouldn't work in this case with the company's restrictions
*I know this is not a new issue, but most of the posts are a few years old and their solutions (usually re-registering the file) have not worked for me.
```

Comment: Can't you browse to find the control in the folder you registered it from? Is Microstation a 32-bit or 64 bit install?

Comment: MicroStation is a 32-Bit install. I can find the control in Syswow64 and can browse to it within the IDE. But when i try to "ok" the browse window nothing happens. It still says "MISSING" in the list of references. Its almost like its ignoring it

Comment: Did you run regsrv32 on the  MSCOMCT2.OCX and MSCOMCTL files? Did you run it in Adminstrator mode?

Comment: Cmd was run as admin. I don't have MSCOMCT2.OCX in either the Syswow64 or System32 folder. Is that needed for MSCOMCTL to work? I havent had it in the past?

Comment: Depends on the functions you're using - but if you didn't need it in the past you won't need it now.

Comment: Make sure the MISSING reference is unchecked and then scroll down your references to see if you can find the correct available version of "`Microsoft Common Controls` and check that one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Problem has been solved. It was a combination of a couple of things based on dbmitch's answer.
By unchecking the missing control, closing down the host program and rebooting. Then opening up the VBA file and searching for the "Microsoft Common Controls" and selecting it. Even though the text was the exact same as the "Missing" one it seems to have done the trick.
I did do that step, but didn't close down the program and start again in between.
Thanks for your help guys!